# Mail trigger error

Tags: php, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am getting the following error. Can you please help me to fix it

**Trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER notifyMe
ON sb_clients
AFTER UPDATE
AS
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'DB AutoMailer',
@recipients = 'mail@mail.com',
@body = 'The DB has changed',
@subject = 'DB Change'
```

**Error**

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON sb_clients
AFTER UPDATE
AS
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = '' at line 2
```

Comment: Check the mysql reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html looks like it should be something similar to `CREATE TRIGGER notifyMe AFTER UPDATE no sb_clients`

Comment: @bradbury9 I checked it but still have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In your error it says "*that corresponds to your MySQL server version*" so I guess you are using MySQL as your database. You have a couple of error:

1. The `sp_send_dbmail` is a SQL Server function
2. The order in the `CREATE TRIGGER` sentence is wrong according to MySQL reference.

It should be something similar to:

```
CREATE TRIGGER notifyMe
AFTER UPDATE
ON sb_clients
[Your trigger code]
```